# Getting somehow the Article ID in an Alternate Layout for Custom Fields

Tags: custom-field, joomla-4.x

I am creating an Alternate Layout of /components/com_fields/layouts/field/render.php to change the layout of some given Custom Fields. And there I need the ID of the article in order to give a unique #id to the container.

There I wanted/needed to fetch the Article ID, but the Layout does not seem to have any information about the context.

I had first thought that the following could work:

```
$id   = $app->input->getCmd('id', '');
```

It indeed gives the article id... but only if you are on an **Article** View.
If you are on a **Blog** View, it gives the ID of the category.

So would there be some direct or indirect way (by overriding another file for example) to get that Article ID in a Blog view?

Txs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Article data is not available in that layout. What you can do is create an override of `components/com_fields/layouts/fields/render.php` and modify it to pass the article to `field/render.php` layout. You'd have to change this line:

```
$content = FieldsHelper::render($context, 'field.' . $layout, array('field' => $field));
```

To this:

```
$content = FieldsHelper::render($context, 'field.' . $layout, array('item' => $item, 'field' => $field));
```

And then in the `field/render.php` layout access the article ID like this:

```
$id = $displayData['item']->id;
```

Comment: Thank you soooooooo much @Sharky for this answer! It works perfectly and avoids making an override/alternate layout for the blog view itself. This is a much more universal solution indeed.